# SQLite query to select columns from table if a particular column value is NULL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, isnull

I have a sqlite db with 1 table and 4 columns in that table. One of these column is optional and may contain NULL values. I want to get values in other 3 columns if this column is null.

For example,

```
column 1    column 2    column 3    column4
a           b                       d
e           f           g           h
i           j                       l
```

What I want to achieve in terms of sqlite is this:

```
SELECT column1 WHERE column3 IS NULL;
```

Since IS NULL doesn't work in SQLite, I have no idea how to achieve this. I am an iOS developer with very little db knowledge. Any help will be much appreciated.

UPDATE1: @rptwsthi suggested to include default values in column 3, which will definitely solve my problem. But, I think this has to be done when creating the database, am I correct? Or can this be done any other way?

UPDATE2: I did refer the SQLite documentation about IS NULL and IS NOT NULL. But only IS NOT NULL is returning the value and IS NULL doesn't work. It doesn't even throw an error.

UPDATE3: I see  in column 3 when I don't have a value. Also I am using Terminal commands. So my code is

```
SELECT column1 WHERE column3 IS NULL;
```

Regards,
iSee

Comment: Here is a suggestion, add a default value to your column3 and run query according to that.

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) on the SQLite homepage, SQLite does indeed support `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` ... what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: I did refer to that link before coming here but sadly, IS NULL doesn't work only IS NOT NULL is functional. I saw that in my db and also in some other forums.

Comment: Are you sure that your column is really `NULL` and not an empty string for example?

Comment: @omz please see the UPDATE 3. It shows as <null> in place of empty column entry. So I presumed it is null.

Comment: Can we please see the code that you are executing; as you can see many people believe `IS NULL` does work appropriately so the issue may lie with your code rather than SQLite itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both
>   of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL,
>   then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator
>   evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not,
>   then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is
>   1 (true).

According to this, `IS NULL` should work just fine in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does support IS NULL functionality

can you give you code where you are writing query in xcode

I tried IS NULL in my sqllite and it worked great..